# What is K-Lipschitz and how do I use it to prove this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

So, I'm completely lost here. Can someone explain to me what K-Lipshitz is? And how I'm supposed to prove this problem?

Comment: They defined it right there. It is shorthand for "Lipschitz with constant $K$".

Comment: @Ian I guess my question is moreso, why is it defined like that? Does it have any other meaning?

Comment: Regarding an intuition for being Lipschitz, it is a condition/property stronger than continuity and weaker than differentiability.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the quotient $\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}\right|=\dfrac{|g(x)-g(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq K \to |f'(x)| \leq K, \forall x \in A.$

To prove continuity of $f$ at $x=a$, let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{K}$, then: if $|x-a| < \delta \to |f(x)-f(a)| \leq K|x-a| < K\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{K} = \epsilon$.